# Transfer a working Windows XP installation to USB pen

Tags: windows-xp, usb-flash-drive

I would like to put my working windows xp installation on a usb pen and get rid of the hard disk (it's a video poker machine so performance of usb is not an issue and hd break very easily).
How can I achieve a perfect and bootable copy from my hd to my pendrive?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Clone\Restore your installed XP to usb-hd](http://reboot.pro/12428/), including comments.